# hector slam not disaplying map in rviz

Tags: hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am following these steps below to run my hector slam in rviz :

** **README.txt****

```
  Postprocessing Logfile example ==
```

Download this file:
http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/downloads/detail?name=Team_Hector_MappingBox_RoboCup_2011_Rescue_Arena.bag&can=2&q=

```
   Open a new terminal window, type:
       rosmake hector_slam

 Launch the tutorial launch file provided in the hector_slam_launch package:
     roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch

    Open another terminal, enter the directory of the .bag file and type:
  rosbag play Team_Hector_MappingBox_RoboCup_2011_Rescue_Arena.bag --clock
```

Before this i installed ros using  this command **sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam**

But when I am running my second command which is the Ros launch its showing a warning sign:

> ```
> [ INFO] [1439891300.286474566]: HectorSM p_map_update_angle_threshold_: 0.060000
> ```

```
  [ INFO] [1439891300.286495451]: HectorSM p_laser_z_min_value_: -1.000000
 [ INFO] [1439891300.286515964]: HectorSM p_laser_z_max_value_: 1.000000
 [ INFO] [1439891300.329699919]: Successfully initialized hector_geotiff MapWriter plugin TrajectoryMapWriter.
 [ INFO] [1439891300.329809825]: Geotiff node started
 [ WARN] [1439891320.241781835]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after       

  20.002011 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once.
```

In the rviz display panel its also showing a warning sign

```
Global Status: Warn   
  Fixed Frame
 No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
```

The rosabag file is running but no map /visualization is being displayed in rviz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216031/hector-slam-not-disaplying-map-in-rviz/) by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-18**:
Hi, what do you get when you run `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree`? I don't need you have the /map frame. You need that to produce the map.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-18**:
Put this line in your .launch file:

or

**Comment by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on 2015-08-18**:
when and where shud i run this command `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` and in which line i mean where i shud put that code of yours **node pkg**

**Comment by [atech1380](https://answers.ros.org/users/23609/atech1380/) on 2015-08-18**:
I'm having the same issue! I edited tutorial.launch in the hector_slam_launch/launch folder, adding:

as psprox96 suggests.

This got rid of the warnings but still no map...

**Comment by [atech1380](https://answers.ros.org/users/23609/atech1380/) on 2015-08-18**:
Nevermind, it is making the map, I just didn't have the right topics watched in RVIZ, doh!

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-18**:
You run that command in the terminal, like how you rosmake the packages. Do you know where is your .launch file? The one you need to run to get the INFO.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-18**:
Yup, and make sure you set your Global Frame in Rviz to /map and LaserScan to /scan.

**Comment by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on 2015-08-18**:
I just directly type the rosmake command and the follow up code in the terminal and then open an another terminal then go to the directly that contains the bag file and then execute it. I don't go to  any directory that contains the .launch file.I  just type it when i open my terminal

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-19**:
Have you run rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree? Can I know the result?

Your command is: roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch. So the package is hector_slam_launch.
Type:
roscd hector_slam_launch
in your terminal.

And open up the tutorial.launch file and add the node pkg line inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears the rviz config does not get loaded correctly (at least on Indigo) and for this reason the rviz Displays are not properly set up. You'll have to manually add the "Map" display to see the map. See also the [rviz Map Display](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Map) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mruniverse](https://answers.ros.org/users/23403/mruniverse/) on 2015-08-19**:
Hi i just added the map icon in the display ans /map to it and it wrked.Thanks stefan
And by the way the waring is still there but i can see the map so thats ok right? And also I didint use rosmake just directly roslaunch as mentioned in the tutorial